# template vector function compile with gcc 4.8.1

Tags: templates, gcc, vector, makefile

I have these routines to work with Mat matrices. These codes have been compiled and worked seamlessly until I bring them to Ubuntu 12.04 to compile using 'make'. I also tried to upgrade gcc to v.4.8.1 but the errors persist

So I come down to a simple test code to check template usage with the compiler:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

template <class A_Type> 
class calc
{
  public:
    A_Type a,b;
    typename vector<A_Type> arr;
    A_Type multiply(A_Type x, A_Type y);
    A_Type add(A_Type x, A_Type y);
    A_Type arr_multi(A_Type x, A_Type y);
};

template <class A_Type> 
A_Type calc<A_Type>::arr_multi(A_Type x,A_Type y)
{
  //arr.clear();
  //arr.push_back(x);
  //arr.push_back(y);
  //return arr[0]*arr[1];

    a = 5; b = 10;
  return a*b;
}

template <class A_Type> 
A_Type calc<A_Type>::multiply(A_Type x,A_Type y)
{
  return x*y;
}

template <class A_Type> 
A_Type calc<A_Type>::add(A_Type x, A_Type y)
{
  return x+y;
}
```

the line creating error is

```
typename vector<A_Type> arr;
```

I thought of typename keyword from an example elsewhere. Originally, it was

```
vector<A_Type> arr;
```

but both were erroneous

What is going on here? error from the same code

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

typename has nothing to do here. It should only be used for dependent names.

By removing typename and adding #include, it should compile (but not link since there is no main).

Comment: thanks! it all works fine. I forgot to include <vector>